# How to visualize objects in darkness

Tags: lighting, low-poly

Below I've an image of my current scene, and two images of what I want to achieve. Now the question is, how can I visualize objects in low light, as you can see the current scene isn't that attractive however the pic from kentucky route zero is soul capturing, so what should I do? Any type of guidance will be appreciated c:

Current Scene:

[image]

Required Output:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Work with different shades of black**

The images you mention to be the goal you want to achieve do not care about the *real* colour of objects. Instead they make use of different shades of black to create an illusion of depth and to distinguish different silhouettes.

- Use a *clean black* for the frontmost objects. E.g. the motorcycle, the truck and the pier.
- Add more dark blues to the mix the farther an object is away to allow distinguishing shapes and silhouettes. E.g. the night sky, the stalagmites.
- Overlay greys to make things look fuzzy & blurred. E.g. the trees next to the street, the caverns.
- Add light-sources to *backlight* things you want to emphasize. E.g. the motorcycle, the truck.

Comment: @dot_Spo0t Can you share a tutorial link or reference please?

Comment: @Weaboo I literally just described what the images you linked do on a visual level. If you need a technical tutorial on how to achieve this you should probably ask a specific question on that where you also state the tools you use, etc.